# convert ndarray to string and print line by line

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print a variable cp with type ndarray.

```
type(cp) 
print cp

    Output:
    <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
    [ 2500.          2498.9888893   2497.86349278  2496.614551    2495.23344426
      2493.71218042  2492.04338019  2490.22025987  2488.23661229  2486.08678611
      2483.76566391  2481.26863949  2478.59159445  2475.73087472  2472.68326689
      2469.44597486  2466.01659689  2462.39310325  2458.57381455  2454.55738096
      2450.34276235  2445.92920938]
```

I want to print the output as:

```
    2500
    2498.98
    2497.86
    ....
    ...
```

How can I convert `ndarray` to `str` and print as shown?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a numpy array.

**In a loop:**

```
for n in a:
    print("  %.2f" % n)
```

**As a one-liner:**

```
print("\n".join("  %.2f" % n for n in a))
```

**Sample data:**

```
a = np.array([
    2500., 2498.9888893, 2497.86349278, 2496.614551, 2495.23344426,
    2493.71218042, 2492.04338019, 2490.22025987, 2488.2366123, 2486.0867861,
    2483.76566391, 2481.26863949, 2478.59159445, 2475.7308747, 2472.6832669,
    2469.44597486, 2466.01659689, 2462.39310325, 2458.5738145, 2454.557380,
    2450.34276235, 2445.92920938
])
```

Comment: print ("\n".join("%.2f" % n for n in a))
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray

Comment: My sample data does not contain commas after every element. IS that a problem that I get error?

Comment: I converted array to list using: b= a.tolist() and print("\n".join("  %.2f" % n for n in b)). Error:  float argument required, not list

Comment: Use a debugger, or maybe try `"%s %s" % (n, type(n))` to try to debug.